# When trying to create a table using clojure.java.sql/create-table I get the exception

Tags: sql, exception, batch-file, clojure

When trying to create a table using clojure.java.sql/create-table I get the exception:

```
batch entry 0: near "-": syntax error
  [Thrown class java.sql.BatchUpdateException]
```

The create-table call looks like this:

```
   (sql/create-table :stories
        [:story-id :integer "PRIMARY KEY"]
        [:story-name :text]
        [:story-name-url :text]
        [:category :text]
        [:genre-one :text]
        [:genre-two :text]
        [:created-on :text]
        [:updated-on :text]
        [:review-count :integer]
        [:chapter-count :integer]
        [:word-count :integer]
        [:rating :integer]
        [:language :integer]
        [:is-complete :boolean]
        [:is-crossover :boolean]
        [:type :text]
        [:pairing :text]))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that fields can't have the '-' character in them. Changing the '-' to '_' will fix the problem.

Comment: Yes. A lot of the Clojure code I see uses keywords with - instead of _ in them. I think it happens because Clojure users are allowed to use - inside function names so it has become the defacto space-like character. I figure I'm not the only who keeps making this mistake.